# 500 internal server error while downloading images using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, internal-server-error

I'm getting the 500 Internal Server Error by running the following script, even though I'm downloading and inserting to the DB 80 images at a time:

```
<?php

function download_remote_file($file_url, $save_to)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
    file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
}

function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

require_once('sqlconnect.php');
$time_start = microtime_float();
$query="SELECT * FROM GAMES WHERE GAME_IMAGE LIKE '%cache%' LIMIT 0, 80";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $game_img = $row['GAME_IMAGE'];
  $gameDB_id = $row['GAME_DBID'];
  chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/game/');
  if(!file_exists($gameDB_id))
  {
  mkdir($gameDB_id);
  }
  if(strlen(strstr($game_img,'boxart')) == 0)
  {
      $game_img = $game_img.'/boxart/original/front/'.$gameDB_id.'-1.jpg'; 
  }

  $game_img_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/game/'.$gameDB_id;
  chmod($game_img_path,0777);
  $game_img_name = $gameDB_id.'.jpg';
 $gamefullpath = 'http://www.someSite.nl/img/game/'.$gameDB_id.'/'.$game_img_name;
 if(!file_exists($game_img_path.'/'.$game_img_name ))
 {
  download_remote_file($game_img, realpath($game_img_path) . '/'.$game_img_name); 

  $bytes = filesize($game_img_path.'/'.$game_img_name );
  $KB = round($bytes / 1024, 2);
  if($KB > 50)
  {
      echo "The ID number ".$gameDB_id. " has an invalid image URL, look it up on gamedb.net! <br />";
  }
 }
   $query2 = "UPDATE GAMES SET GAME_IMAGE = '$gamefullpath' WHERE GAME_DBID = '$gameDB_id' AND GAME_DBID";
  $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("error!");
  //$nr_of_files = count($game_img_path);
  //echo "Nr of images downloaded:".$nr_of_files;
}

mysql_close($con);
$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Downloading and adding to the database took ".$time." seconds <br />";
$message = "The specified images have been downloaded!";
echo $message;
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong which forces the server to stop? Or in case it's not efficient what can I do to make it so. Or maybe the problem is some server configuration.

Server:

```
Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny13 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.7(2008-08-11) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g Server
```

Your help is much appreciated.

UPDATE (log):

```
‎[Wed Jan 11 08:58:39 2012] [notice] mod_fcgid: call /home/someSiteName/public_html/admin/download_game_img.php with wrapper /home/someSiteName/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi
```

UPDATE (time):

*about 100 seconds.*

UPDATE (die):

I put a die after this line and the error seems to be here:

```
download_remote_file($game_img, realpath($game_img_path) . '/'.$game_img_name);
```

Comment: An messages in your PHP error log? How long is this operation taking? Standard PHP.ini configuration is going to allow 30 seconds wall time -- you can of course chnage that but you need to know what's going on

Comment: Yuri and @Murray McDonald, I have updated my question :)

Comment: Could be some config. Timeout or something. Read manual for correct directive values: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout
Also you should really try to debug it step-by-step by running each function separately, putting `die` from line to line at least.

Comment: That's your webserver's activity log -- one can also have a "PHP error log" (always a good idea on a production server) -- it is configurable via the php.ini file -- i would recommend the following settings:
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = On
error_log = /path/to/dir/with/proper_permissions/php_errors.log

Basically a http 500 just means something "went wrong" at the server -- you really need to know exactly what -- my guess is that you've exceeded some configurable limit (either in the PHP setup or the webserver setup) -- what webserver r u using?

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald The server I'm using is in the question :)

Comment: Comments don't allow "newlines" in them -- the php.ini config directives above are each on a separate line in the file -- find the existing entries and change them -- or comment them out and add new ones -- be sure to search the file to ensure directives don't occurr more than once -- the "last" one always wins in the case of duplicate directives

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald thanks for your clear instructions.

Comment: Yuri and @MurrayMcDonald and please see my last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the default php script's  maximum execution time is **30 seconds** and your page is taking more than 100 seconds.

you can increase the maximum execution time for your php scripts using .htaccess file

add the following lines to your **.htaccess** file

```
php_value max_execution_time 8000
php_value max_input_time 4000
```

you can also set the limit in **php.ini** file

```
max_execution_time 8000
max_input_time 4000
```

Comment: I will try this and if it works I will accept your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well the htacess method would only work if "AllowOverride" is on in the server config -- best thing to do is to get the PHP error log working -- then the error should show up in that log or the Apache error log

Comment: @Nima -- sorry I am not "getting" whatever you are referring to

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald, I meant the download_remote_file method is causing the problem, because the script stops when I use "or die(blabla)". But I'm doing what you suggested with the php.ini and I'm also trying the php.ini approach of max_execution_time and max_input_time. I will let you know the result :)

Comment: OK -- I see now -- so you've tracked it to the "download_remote_file" -- and of course you have no control over how much time it will take to retrieve the file from a remote site -- but do yourself a favour and make sure your have the error logging turned on -- now there is the PHP maximum exectution time setting to chnage but as I remeber there might also being something in the Apache http.conf -- its been 4 years since I did active Apache admin

Comment: BTW I no longer remember if you need to stop/restart Apache when you make a PHP.ini setting change -- I think if it's running as a module you do and if it's running CGI you don't -- another option is to use "ini_set" at the top of your script -- that way you can change a setting for the script but leave the ini-file setting intact for other scripts

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald thanks I learnt much from you. I'm trying everything you suggested. I already restarted the server BTW.